# Checking multiple upload inputs - undefined variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to check the size of uploaded document to 2 separate input fields, I get

> TypeError: fileUpload1.files[0] is undefined

However there is an if statement to avoid this but not working (if there is no upload attached)

I have tried moving the position of the if statement but same issue, am I missing something obvious, JS as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Upload() {
        var fileUpload = document.getElementById("Evidence11");
        var fileUpload1 = document.getElementById("Evidence12");

        if (typeof (fileUpload1.files) != "undefined") {
        var size1 = parseFloat(fileUpload1.files[0].size / 1024).toFixed(0);
        }


        if (typeof (fileUpload.files) != "undefined") {
            var size = parseFloat(fileUpload.files[0].size / 1024).toFixed(0);
            size = parseFloat(size) + parseFloat(size1);
            if (size >= 4096) { 
                    alert( 
                      "File too Big, please select a file less than 4mb"); 
                      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  "The file too big(" + size + "kb), please select a file less than 4mb.";
                } else { 
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  "File size is less that 4mb (" + size + "KB) and ok to continue.";
                    var element = document.getElementById("nextBButton");
                    element.classList.add("revButton");
                } 

        } else {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
        }
    }
</script>


<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Say fileUpload.files = [] but fileUpload.files[0] will be undefined. check for length

Answer (score 1):

You're checking if the files attribute is undefined or not, it is by default an array-like object, so it passes the check, because fileUpload.files is not null but a `[object FileList]`. but fileUpload.files[0] is null, because it has no elements inside of it, you can either check for the first item in the files array to not be null, or check its length.

```
if (fileUpload1.files[0]) {
   //do your thing 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function Upload() {
    var fileUpload = document.getElementById("Evidence11");
    var fileUpload1 = document.getElementById("Evidence12");

    if (fileUpload1 && fileUpload1.files.length) {
    var size1 = parseFloat(fileUpload1.files[0].size / 1024).toFixed(0);
    }


    if (fileUpload && fileUpload.files.length) {
        var size = parseFloat(fileUpload.files[0].size / 1024).toFixed(0);
        size = parseFloat(size) + parseFloat(size1);
        if (size >= 4096) { 
                alert( 
                  "File too Big, please select a file less than 4mb"); 
                  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  "The file too big(" + size + "kb), please select a file less than 4mb.";
            } else { 
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  "File size is less that 4mb (" + size + "KB) and ok to continue.";
                var element = document.getElementById("nextBButton");
                element.classList.add("revButton");
            } 

    } else {
        alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
    }
}
```